# Maple: How do I show vectors with many elements?

Tags: maple

As the header says: How do I show vectors in their full form, when they have many elements?
Instead of just seeing some vector data that Maple shows, when the vector is too long:

[image: Maple input and output]

I recall seeing a command before that let you change this setting, so Maple shows vectors with up to as many elements as you decide. Can anyone help my memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

*interface(rtablesize=infinity)*.